# Modifying loop to show custom fields just for the active/opened post- Wordpress

Tags: php, loops, wordpress

I need to modify this code to show get custom fields just for the post on which the user currently is.

```
// this needs to be modified
<?php
global $post;
$args = array('category' => 37, 'post_type' => 'post' ); 
$postslist = get_posts( $args ); 
foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
?> 
// end this needs to be modified

<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "Title", true) ): ?>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Title", true); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Because this will be included, I cannot make it just with get_post_meta.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ignores the loop and only shows the custom field for the current page, notice get_the_ID():

```
<?php if( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "Title", true) ): ?>
    <p><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "Title", true); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
global $post;
$args = array('category' => 37, 'post_type' => 'post' ); 
$postslist = get_posts( $args ); 
foreach ($postslist as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
}
?>
```

And this will output all custom fields named "Title" from within the loop:

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array('category' => 37, 'post_type' => 'post' ); 
$postslist = get_posts( $args ); 
foreach ($postslist as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);

    echo('<p>'.get_post_meta($post->ID, "Title", true).'</p>');
}
?>
```

Comment: Does that error message say what line the error is on? I don't see anything missing in the sample code here.

Comment: Yes, but it was my mistake.. all I need to do is to omit this loop and only set get_the_ID() to all custom field calls. Thank you very much, you guided me to the right track! Thanks